# Matlab- zero padding

Tags: matlab

How to do this on matlab?

zero pad the face image with a five‐pixel
thick rim around the borders of the
image. show the resulting image.

Must be manual codes on script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save this function as `create_padded_image.m`

```
function padded_image = create_padded_image(image, padding)

if nargin < 2
    % if no padding passed - define it.
    padding = 5;
end

if nargin < 1
    % let's create an image if none is given
    image = rand(5, 4)
end

% what are the image dimensions?
image_size = size(image);


% allocate zero array of new padded image
padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2))

% write image into the center of padded image
padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2)) = image;

end
```

Then call it like this:

```
% read in image - assuming that your image is a grayscale image
$ image = imread(filename);
$ padded_image = create_padded_image(image)
```

Comment: So this is all? how do i call tix function in matlab? I'm very new to matlab, so I couldn't really solve it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: yep, that's all you need. if no padding is passed, this function will create one. If no image is given - the function will create one too.

Comment: Hi, I've tried out your programme for the first part that u've provided just now...and undertand,
but I need this in script form, not by typing in matlab, so its kind of a trouble to solve it.
so for tix current 1, I juz type it in script...
then at the matlab i juz do a "I= imread('picture')".....
to solve it?

Comment: no, you have to save the code into an m file. then you need to call this function.

Comment: Okay I've tested, its great!!
so when i wan to add a picture? I call it from?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I nv check the tick.
This code applies for any dimension of picture?
if its colour image then it cant be use?

Comment: bcos I've got this....
??? Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than
non-singleton
subscripts

Error in ==> create_padded_image at 17
    padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1),
    padding+1:padding+image_size(2)) = image;

Error in ==> create_padded_image at 9
    padded_image = create_padded_image(image)

Comment: I'm so sorry to disturb u, I don't mind creating another slot for u to ans...so I can tick one more for u....
u've been a great help to me. tks alot..

Comment: For padding a color image, you'd have to modify the source slightly since a color RGB image is a MxNx3 matrix. Call the padding function for each dimension (color, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework, so I will just give you a hint:

In MATLAB it is very easy to put the content of one matrix into another at precisely the correct place. Check out the help for matrix indexing and you should be able to solve it.

Comment: As i'm very new towards matlab so I couldn't really understand on the coding parts.
I can only understand the concept of it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you want to code this yourself, but for reference, you can use the [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/padarray.html) function. Example:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
II = padarray(I,[5 5],0,'both');
imshow(II)
```

[image: screenshot]

Note this works also for multidimensional matrices (RGB images for example)