# Matlab- zero padding(2)

Tags: matlab

Anyone can help? Don't know why got error? ???

> ```
> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
> subscripts Error in ==> create_padded_image at 17
> padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1),
> padding+1:padding+image_size(2)) = image; Error in ==>
> create_padded_image at 9 padded_image = create_padded_image(image)
> ```

```
function padded_image = create_padded_image(image, padding)  
if nargin < 2         
    % if no padding passed - define it.         
    padding = 5; 
end
if nargin < 1     
    % let's create an image if none is given
    image = imread('GreyScale.bmp');
    padded_image = create_padded_image(image) 

end  
    % what are the image dimensions? 
    image_size = size(image);   
    % allocate zero array of new padded image 
    padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2));
    % write image into the center of padded image 
    padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2)) = image; 
end
```

Comment: Anyone can help? Don't know why got error?

??? Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts 

Error in ==> create_padded_image at 17 padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2)) = image; 

Error in ==> create_padded_image at 9 padded_image = create_padded_image(image)

Comment: This works for gray-scale images. From the error message I suspect that you have given a colour image as input. To fix it you need to pad all 3 colour components at the same time.

Comment: I had changed it to this, for all 3 components, after that i used [imshow('picture')] but i couldn't get the display picture that has zero padded......any idea?>>>
% allocate zero array of new padded image 
    padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2), 2*padding + image_size(3));
% write image into the center of padded image 
    padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2), padding+1:padding+image_size(3)) = image;

Comment: You probably don't want to pad in the third (colour) dimension. Try changing that to: 
padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2), 3);
and then:
padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2), :) = image

Comment: I've tried your method it works for the coding, but how do I display the result in picture form?
So I can check whether my picture is zero-padded?
I must use [imshow('picturename')] or [imshow('padded_image')].
Cuz I couldn't get it.
tks.

Comment: just do: imshow(padded_image)

Comment: I've tried both [imshow(padded_image)] or [imshow('padded_image')]....both can't work.....do you have any idea?
so sorry about it.

Comment: Use `image(padded_image)`. `imshow` is in the image processing toolbox.

Comment: function padded_image = create_padded_image2(image, padding)
if nargin < 2         
    % if no padding passed - define it.         
    padding = 5; 
end
if nargin <  1
    image = imread('colour.jpg');
end  
    % what are the image dimensions? 
    image_size = size(image);   
    % allocate zero array of new padded image 
    padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2), 3);
    % write image into the center of padded image 
    padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2), :) = image;
    imshow(padded_image)
end

Comment: Ive only got this error>>>
??? Error using ==> image
Error using ==> image
Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData

Comment: for context, I'm adding a link to your previous related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579477/matlab-zero-padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
image_size = size(image);
padded_image = zeros(2*padding + image_size(1), 2*padding + image_size(2), size(image,3), class(image));
padded_image(padding+1:padding+image_size(1), padding+1:padding+image_size(2), :) = image;
```

Comment: Hey Nzbuu tks! It works fine now!!
can i know whats this? "size(image,3), class(image)"
it solved my problem!

Comment: size(U,3) returns the size of the U along the 3rd dimension, which is the number of colour channels. class(U) returns the class of U. Then zeros(...) will create something with the same number of colour channels and the same data type.

Comment: So size means that the dimensions are not affected?
and Class means the level are also not affected?
and zeros(...) will create something which match the size and class of this?
Tks alot for your help! :)